# Python PDB only stepping into single file?

Tags: python, pdb

I'm trying to debug a fairly complex django project that obviously has a ton of calls to built in functions, other classes, and misc custom methods.  What I want to do is put the pdb.set_trace() in just the file I am concerned with (ie. the value of a product) and when I do a step command in PDB, have it just go the other functions I'm calling within that file.  I don't want it to go to any other file, django method, or python low level code.

Is this possible?

As a note I'm already using the amazing [pdb++](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdbpp/).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. Just put the `set_trace()` call in that module, and if needed, add additional breakpoints using the `b` command for the other functions, or use multiple `set_trace()` calls.

Then, when stepping through the code, use `n` (or `next`) to skip over function calls that would take you out of the module. Or use `unt` (`until`) to run code until the next line is being executed (use this to get out of a long loop). Whenever the interpreter hits one of your breakpoints or `set_trace()` calls it'll stop there, regardless.